# In Bioconductor, what is the difference between the following commands: install.packages() and pkgInstall()?

Tags: r, bioconductor

It appears that when I tried to install a bioconductor package, the only command that correctly worked was install.packages()? Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: You should use `biocLite()` for installing packages on Bioconductor. See https://bioconductor.org/install/#install-bioconductor-packages . I don't know what `pkgInstall()` is.